For the left action $G\times S \to S$, $\psi: G \to A(S)$ is a homomorphism, where $A(S)$ is group of permutations of $S$. Is $\psi$ onto necessarily?
In the Abstract Algebra book of D.S. Malik, John N. Mordeson, this theorem says that the homomorphism $\psi:G\to A(S)$ is onto.
The statement is: Let $G$ be a group, and $S$ be a $G$-set. Then the left action of $G$ on $S$ induces a homomorphism from $G$ onto $A(S),$ where $A(S)$ is the group of all permutations of $S$.
Now I took the Group $S_3$ and the non-empty set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Since $S_3$ is a proper subgroup of $S_4$, I define action $S_3\times\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ as, $\sigma\cdot a= \sigma(a)\quad\forall\sigma\in S_3, \forall a\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ with defining that $\sigma(4)=4$ since, $4$ is fixed by every element of $S_3.$
Now, number of all permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $4!=24$, and it is obvious that the permutations form a group which is $S_4$. Then, it is impossible to have an onto homomorphism from $S_3$ to $S_4.$

There has to be some additional hypothesis on $G$. If you choose $G={1}$ the trivial group, $\psi$ is never onto, unless you act on a one-element set.

The image of $\psi$ is a group of permutations of $S$, just not all of them. What is the precise statement of the theorem? Also, please include the question in your post even if it duplicates part of the title.

If that is the entire statement, no context, nothing else, then the statement is false. It is also possible that there is a typo of "into" rendered as "onto" (or a different convention of the meaning of the word "onto").
